# Need json_encode to return sorted array

Tags: arrays, json, perl, sorting

I need json_encode to return a sorted array, but can't figure out how.

Here's my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::PP;

use English;   ## use names rather than symbols for special variables

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';

opendir my $dfh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $OS_ERROR";
my %genus_species;  ## store matching entries in a hash

for my $file (readdir $dfh)
{
    next unless $file =~ /.png$/;  ## entry must have .png extension
    my $genus = $file =~ s/\d*\.png$//r;
    push(@{$genus_species{$genus}}, $file);   ## push to array,the @{} is to cast the single entry to a reference to an list
}

print "var galleryarray = "; ## HTML Variable element ( <var> )
print (encode_json(\%genus_species)); ## define array in Javascript outputting elements containing image file names
```

Here's part of the output, showing the unsorted elements:

```
var galleryarray = {"Polygonum_pensylvanicum":["Polygonum_pensylvanicum2.png","Polygonum_pensylvanicum3.png","Polygonum_pensylvanicum1.png"]
```

Notice that the indexed file names are unsorted numerically.

Before posting, I tried adding the following **sort** function below the **push** function:

```
sort(@{$genus_species{$genus}}, $file);
```

Unfortunately, that caused an error; specifically "Useless use of sort in void context."

Please advise how I can output a sorted array using **json_encode**. Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `sort` to see how it works?

Comment: I've read extensively about how to sort json arrays, and even more experienced computer hobbyists appear to have difficulties.

Comment: You're working with *perl* arrays and functions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very inexperienced with coding... but am trying to learn.

Comment: `map { $gs{$_} = [ sort @{$gs{$_}} ] } keys %gs`

Comment: By the way, `galleryarray` is a misnomer. You have assigned an object to it.

Comment: My intent was to define "var galleryarray" as a variable compatible with HTML.

Comment: jhnc... thanks for the code... where should I place it in the script (l'm inexperienced)?

Comment: jhnc... Your map/sort expression works! I don't understand how, but it does! Thank you!!! By the way, I placed your code above the "next unless" expression.

Comment: I guess you mean javascript rather than html but that variable still contains an [object](https://www.json.org). You sort before you need the sorted data but after you have finished assignments (otherwise you keep re-sorting, which is inefficient). You may find it useful to read the Perl documentation on [`map`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map), [`keys`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys), and study [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut).

Comment: My purpose for creating this JSON array of .png photo files is for a self-loading JavaScript slideshow that displays one or more plant photos per plant. Hopefully my efforts to refine this script weren't in vain.

Comment: I just moved the "map/sort" expression from above the "next unless" expression to above the "print" expressions to avoid "re-sorting, which is inefficient."

Answer (score 3):

The following is the proper syntax:

```perl
@{$genus_species{$genus}} = sort @{$genus_species{$genus}};
```

It's inefficient to repeatedly sort the arrays. Instead, you should create a second loop after the first.

```perl
for my $genus (keys(%genus_species)) {
   @{$genus_species{$genus}} = sort @{$genus_species{$genus}};
}
```

or

```perl
@{$genus_species{$_}} = sort @{$genus_species{$_}}
   for keys(%genus_species);
```

---

But your strings have a mix of text and numbers, so a natural sort would be better.

```perl
use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );

@{$genus_species{$_}} = natsort @{$genus_species{$_}}
   for keys(%genus_species);
```

---

If you want to the keys to be sorted too, replace

```perl
encode_json(...)
```

with

```perl
JSON::PP->new->utf8->canonical->encode(...)
```

or the faster

```perl
Cpanel::JSON::XS->new->utf8->canonical->encode(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, ikegami, for all your help!!! I plan to use the key/value pairs returned by this script to load plant photos into a JavaScript slideshow. Unfortunately, I’m concerned that I may have underestimated the difficulty of this next task.

Comment: ikegami--- Using "JSON::PP->new->utf8->canonical->encode_json(\%genus_species);" results in the error: encountered object 'JSON::PP=HASH(0x7fe28881d888)', but neither allow_blessed nor convert_blessed settings are enabled at /var/folders/z9/... Please advise.

Comment: I pasted your code directly into my script, so there aren't any syntax errors. That said, sorting by genus isn't necessary, but would be nice.

Comment: Wow... You're right! After correcting my mistakes, the keys are now sorted as well. Thank you, ikegami... you're amazing!!!

Answer (score 1):

---UPDATE--- One of our forum members provided a **sort** expression that allows the **json_encode** function to return a sorted array. I want to share his solution to help others.

Here's my revised script that returns a sorted array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::PP;

use English;   ## use names rather than symbols for special variables

my $dir = '/Users/jdm/Desktop/xampp/htdocs/cnc/images/plants';

opendir my $dfh, $dir  or die "Can't open $dir: $OS_ERROR";
my %genus_species;  ## store matching entries in a hash

for my $file (readdir $dfh)
{
    next unless $file =~ /.png$/;  ## entry must have .png extension
    my $genus = $file =~ s/\d*\.png$//r;
    push(@{$genus_species{$genus}}, $file);   ## push to array,the @{} is to cast the single entry to a reference to an list
}

@{$genus_species{$_}} = sort @{$genus_species{$_}}
    for keys(%genus_species);

print (JSON::PP->new->utf8->canonical->encode(\%genus_species)); ## define array in Javascript outputting elements containing image file names
```

Comment: The basic of `map` is to take the input list, apply code in the block to each element, and _return output list_.  This code uses `map` in a "void context", only for its side effects (assignment in the block).  That is misleading and considered a poor practice. Instead, better write an explicit loop: `for my $k (keys %gs) { $gs{$k} = [ sort @{$gs{$k}} ] };`. (I abbreviated the name `%genus_species` to `%gs` ONLY for readability in this comment; keep descriptiive names in code!) This better expresses the logic of processing each element of an existing array (and not needing to return a new list)

Comment: Thanks, zdim, for your explanation of “map.” I’ll have to experiment with your code.

Comment: @zdim My bad. Yes, use `for` here rather than `map` (although: http://pq.tinita.de/?st=1999 ... :-)

Comment: @jhnc hah, "cute" quote ... which is tongue-in-cheek ... i hope

Comment: "_I’ll have to experiment with your code_"  --- it's as basic as things get; you just replace the `map { ...` line with it.  But now you have @ikegami's answer...